# What is the meaning of the notation $x \in 2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In a paper [that is to be published], I encountered following notation:

> $x\in2^{\mathbb{R}^n}$

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3):

In short it means that $x$ is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ as @Augustin says (I don't understand why his answer was downvoted at first hand). If $A$ and $B$ are sets then more general $A^B$ denotes the set of all functions $B\to A$ as @user21820 says. Of course this only makes sense if $2$ is recognized as a set: $$2:=\{0,1\}$$

So the elements of $2^{\mathbb R^n}$ are functions that only take the values $0$ and $1$. Such function $f$ can be identified with the set $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid f(x)=1\}\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ revealing why $2^{\mathbb R^n}$ can also be looked at as the powerset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3):

The notation $x\in 2^A$ has two possible meanings. Some people use it to mean that $x\subseteq A$; for them $2^A$ is simply the power set of $A$. Others use it to mean the set of functions from the set $A$ to the set $2$, where as a set $2=\{0,1\}$; this is a special case of the common usage of $B^A$ to represent the set of all functions from the set $A$ to the set $B$. (Some of us prefer to use ${^BA}$ for that.)

The two interpretations are technically very different: a subset of $A$ is not the same thing as a function from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. However, there is a natural bijection between $\wp(A)$, the family of all subsets of $A$, and ${^A\{0,1\}}$, the family of all functions from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. (Here I’m purposely avoiding the ambiguous notation $2^A$.) Specifically, we can associate to each $x\subseteq A$ its [indicator (or characteristic) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

$$\mathbf{1}_x:A\to\{0,1\}:a\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }a\in x\\
0,&\text{if }a\in A\setminus x\;.
\end{cases}$$

If $x,y\subseteq A$ with $x\ne y$, then $\mathbf{1}_x\ne\mathbf{1}_y$, and each function $f:A\to\{0,1\}$ is $\mathbf{1}_{\{a\in A:f(a)=1\}}$, so the association really is bijective. One could say that the two interpretations of $x\in 2^A$ are really just two different ways of looking at essentially the same thing.

Thus, in practice one can generally just keep reading to see whether $x$ is being treated as a subset of $A$ or as the indicator function of a subset of $A$; context will usually make it clear very quickly which is intended.

Answer (score 2):

This is the powerset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that $x$ is some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$A^B$ is defined as the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$. Thus $2^S$ can be understood as the set of all indicator functions on $S$.

Comment: @MWijnand: What's your point? There's a **vast difference** between "isomorphic to" and "equal to". Ultimately you have to **choose** the meaning for each notation used, and once chosen you should be consistent in using them. Ignoring the fine details is fine only if you know precisely what you are doing.

Comment: Note: Above comment was in response to the asker who has since changed his username to MWc...